# Is Amp & Speakers questions on/off-topic here?

Tags: support

Are Amp & Speakers questions on/off-topic here?

Like amp & speakers power matching.

If not, is there an SE site for that?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there is any SE for this (maybe Music Practice?) but as you may know, in SE these questions are asked after research, and sometimes when it comes to hardware, manufacturer or seller support is more efficient than random users.

Comment: Usually on SE, a very specific question renders a couple lines complete and nuanced answer plus relevant comments from people used to the matter. Precious. And usually better than spending a lot of time searching something embedded in tons of pages, in a field I might not be competent, and therefore might no be able to gather the essence of what I was looking for in the first place. There is a difference between asking something that Google answers in 10 seconds, and a question for which building an answer from all Google results requires time and knowledge, prone to errors/misleading info.

Comment: It's hard to say when we don't know what the question is. There are cases where Amp and Speakers questions could be on topic, and cases where it could not... It must be related to Music listening appreciation and have the basics requirements that all SE sites have.

Comment: Usually, amp and speakers power matching is defined in the hardware specifications, and seems to be more related to electronics than music appreciation, but a lot of audiophile users know a bit about this stuff... I don't know, I hope mods could give their opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to your core question I think there is room for some speaker and amp questions here, but I do not think any question. Specifically power matching I don't think would make sense on this SE.

Specifically speaker and amp repair and set up are cover in the context of practice on Music P&T SE, but that's a limited set of questions. I can see some home/personal equipment basic set up and maintenance as on topic here, but again only some. There are definitely some questions I feel like we should never consider like speaker/amp shopping recommendations.